# Unable to write to my text file in C#

Tags: c#, file-writing

The following code does not write to a text file. Unsure as to why, as I am following my book exactly, to my knowledge. No errors are thrown at run-time, the program runs successfully. The file path is correct and the file mentioned is not currently open

```
String databasePath = "C:\\Users\\Dalton.Riera\\Downloads\\Summer Program Practice 0 Solution Extr\\Summer Program Practice 0 Solution\\DataBase.txt";
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(databasePath, 
    FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
Writer.WriteLine("Test");
Console.ReadKey();
Writer.Close();
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Look at `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: Make sure you do NOT have the file open while trying to write to it.

Comment: Your code as presented works fine (assuming the file path exists and is not in use). Without any details on the error you're getting, I'm voting to close

Comment: Make sure to check the contents of the file *after* the .Close() method.  If you check it while you're waiting on the ReadKey(), the buffer may not have flushed so the file could appear empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append, just [AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
   string databasePath = "C:\\Users\\Dalton.Riera\\Downloads\\Summer Program Practice 0 Solution Extr\\Summer Program Practice 0 Solution\\DataBase.txt";

   File.AppendAllText(databasePath, "Test");
```

In case you insist on `Writer` close it *before* `Console.ReadKey` (when you check the file)

```
// first write into the file
//DONE: do not close IDisposable explicitly, but wrap them into "using"
using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(
  new FileStream(databasePath, 
                 FileMode.Append, 
                 FileAccess.Write))) {
  Writer.WriteLine("Test");
} 

// ... then stop and check file's content
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.ReadKey();
Writer.Close();
```

Please move the line `Console.ReadKey();` after `Writer.Close();`. The function **ReadKey** holds the execution and content is not written to file unless **Write.Close** function is called. So your code should look like:

```
String databasePath = "C:\\Users\\Dalton.Riera\\Downloads\\Summer Program Practice 0 Solution Extr\\Summer Program Practice 0 Solution\\DataBase.txt";
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(databasePath,
FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
Writer.WriteLine("Test");

Writer.Close();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Still fairly new so these simple mistakes are killing me.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst your code should work as written, there could be a caching issue:

I'd suggest adding `writer.Flush()` before your `writer.Close()`.

On top of this, you should probably be `using` the `StreamWriter` not just creating it to ensure that it is correctly disposed of.

Combining these two points would render the following code:

```
    String databasePath = "C:\\Users\\Dalton.Riera\\Downloads\\Summer Program Practice 0 Solution Extr\\Summer Program Practice 0 Solution\\DataBase.txt";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(databasePath, 
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Test");
        Console.ReadKey();
        writer.Flush();
        //writer.Close(); this may or may not be needed.
    }
```

---

Update for C#8:

You can now use block scoped using declarations to tidy this up a bit:

```
String databasePath = "yourpath";
using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(databasePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)));
writer.WriteLine("Test");
Console.ReadKey();
writer.Flush();
//writer.Close(); this may or may not be needed.
```